# jQuery AJAX call not succeeding/running

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using Rapid API to save my users emails and passwords. My send function is being called onclick, but I don't think the program is running through the AJAX call.

I'm not sure what to do. Please help.

*signup.html*

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ShapeBootstrap Clean Template</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">


    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

  <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="img/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="img/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="img/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="img/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png">



    <!-- SCRIPT
    ============================================================-->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src = "script.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  ...

<div class="container">

  <div class="form-wrap">
        <div class="tabs">
            <h3 class="signup-tab"><a class="active" href="#signup-tab-content">Sign Up</a></h3>
            <h3 class="login-tab"><a href="#login-tab-content">Sign In</a></h3>
        </div><!--.tabs-->

        <div class="tabs-content">
            <div id="signup-tab-content" class="active">
                <form class="signup-form">
                    <input type="email" class="input" id="user_email" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Email">
                    <input type="password" class="input" id="user_password" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Password">
                    <button onclick="send()" class="button">Sign Up</button>
                </form><!--.login-form-->
                <div class="help-text">
                    <p>By signing up, you agree to our</p>
                    <p><a href="#">Terms of service</a></p>
                </div><!--.help-text-->
            </div><!--.signup-tab-content-->

            <div id="login-tab-content">
                <form class="login-form" action="" method="post">
                    <input type="text" class="input" id="user_login_email" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email">
                    <input type="password" class="input" id="user_pass" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password">
          <input type="password" class="input" id="user_topic" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Your course choice">

                    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Login">

                </form><!--.login-form-->
            </div><!--.login-tab-content-->
        </div><!--.tabs-content-->
    </div><!--.form-wrap-->
</div>



<!--Footer
==========================-->

<footer>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">Copyright &copy 2013 Shapebootstrap | All Rights Reserved  <br>
        <small>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</small>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            <div class="social pull-right">
                <a href="#"><img src="img/social/googleplus.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/social/dribbble.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/social/twitter.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/social/dribbble.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/social/rss.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</footer>

<!--/.Footer-->
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
tab = $('.tabs h3 a');

tab.on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  tab.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');

  tab_content = $(this).attr('href');
  $('div[id$="tab-content"]').removeClass('active');
  $(tab_content).addClass('active');
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
        var emailInput;
    var passwordInput;
    function send() {
        emailInput = document.getElementById("user_email").value;
        passwordInput = document.getElementById("user_password").valu

e;

    jQuery.ajax({
    url: "",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    data: {
    "email": emailInput,
    "password": passwordInput,
    },
    })
    .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log("HTTP Request Succeeded: " + jqXHR.status);
    console.log(data);
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("HTTP Request Failed");
    })
    .always(function() {
    /* ... */
    });

            }
```

Comment: why are you loading jquery.js file two times ? Also script.js two times in header and footer

Comment: So it is working now ?

Comment: No it is not working @Poria.

Comment: 4things to be modified : 1)Place your jquery.js script above bootstrap.min.js 2)Specify type attribute to button. <button type="button" onclick="send()" class="button">Sign Up</button> 3)Remove content-type in $.ajax 4)Remove double quotes of data values - eg. data: {
    email: emailInput,
    password: passwordInput,
    }; After trying these changes, let know which alert is being called

Comment: @KarthikMR thanks so much. Your first 2 points fixed it. I didn't use your last two points, that code was given to me by Rapid API (but I'll keep it in mind for later). One last thing, the page is taking the input and everything, but it doesn't 'vanish' onclick (the input just stays there on the screen) how do I fix that?

Comment: glad it helped. have made it as an answer. As a part of this forum, you need to accept it if it has solved the issue!. coming to your question, when you click on 'Sign Up' button, its an ajax call you are making, not an default submit action, the input values of these html's will be present.

Comment: Code dump alert! If you don't know which piece of code is likely giving you problems, you may need to invest time into learning what line of code does what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these changes:

1)Place your jquery.js script above bootstrap.min.js

2) Specify type attribute to button. Sign Up.This is coz different browsers interpret the button type differently when no type attribute is specified

3) Remove content-type in $.ajax. This is coz, by default jquery sends the request as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

4) Remove double quotes of data values - eg. data: { email: emailInput, password: passwordInput, };